# How to vertically align text when font is calculating height differently?

Tags: css

I apologize in beforehand if this is a duplicate but I can't seem to find an answer.

I made something that resembles a progress bar. It's a div with p elements inside. However I can't seem to center the p elements vertically.

All i did now was give the parent div some padding and logically the text should be in the middle but it seems like the font is counting the height differently. And so the solution to change the line-height won't work. If I change the font to Verdana the text is aligned but that is not a preferred solution.

Snippet:

```css
div {
    width: 90%;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 1.2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    font-family: 'Hind Guntur', sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 90%;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran|Hind+Guntur" rel="stylesheet">
<div>
  <p>1</p>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for. Your problem was that you had a fixed `height` of `20px` on the `div`. If you change that value to `28px`, your text might vertical-align.

```css
div {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1.2%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 28px;
  font-family: 'Hind Guntur', sans-serif;
}
p {
  font-size: 90%;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran|Hind+Guntur" rel="stylesheet">
<div>
  <p>1</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this

```css
div {
    width: 90%;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 1.2%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    font-family: 'Hind Guntur', sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-size: 90%;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran|Hind+Guntur" rel="stylesheet">
<div>
  <p>1</p>
</div>
```